# Why use '!!' before an expression?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, boolean, eslint, type-coercion

I'm on VSCode with ESLint installed and I tried to type that expression to get a "true" or "false" output

```
const result = goodGuys.includes(guy) ?
```

but it didn't worked and with a quick fix (from ESLint that I don't understand, so here I am lol) of removing the "?" and adding two exclamation marks at the beginning, it work just well.

```
const result = !!goodGuys.includes(guy);
```

Can someone explain this to me please? Thx

Comment: The above snippet isn’t syntactically correct. What exactly is the code supposed to do?

Comment: `includes` always returns a boolean. So, just `const result = goodGuys.includes(guy) ` should be enough

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's just an ESLint thing. `includes` returns a Boolean, so it actually functions like that in code. ESLint sometimes wants to enforce Boolean rules, so `!!` does that for you. It works by using double negation - once to get an inverted Boolean, then again to un-invert it, giving you the Boolean representation of your expression. It's basically the same as this:

```
const result = Boolean(goodGuys.includes(guy));
```

Comment: But, `includes` always returns a boolean. Why does ESLint complain about this?

Comment: I honestly do not know @adiga - I don't use linters.

Comment: But, `new Boolean()` returns an object

Comment: Just `Boolean()` is equivalent to `!!`.

Comment: Oh, of course @SebastianSimon...thanks! I completely forgot about that!